# Intermeediate Value Theorem- Can't solve

Tags: calculus

Let $ f:[0,1]\to [0,1] $ be a continuous function. Show that there exists a $x\in [0,1] $ such that $f(x)=sin(2x)$ .

I have no idea on how to solve it... I guess the first stage is defining $g(x)=f(x)-sin(2x) $ and then showing that there is a value for which $g\leq 0 $ and a value for which $g\geq 0 $ . Here, I can't understand how to find such values... I always get that $g\geq 0 $ , and can't find the other direction of the inequality .

Hope someone will be able to help

Thanks !

Comment: why would you think $g(x)>0$ always?

Comment: $g(0)\geq 0 $ ... because $g(0) = f(0)$ which is non-negative

Comment: I mean $g(x)\geq 0$

Comment: Actually, the constant function $sin2$+ $(1-sin2)/2$ seems like a counterexample.

Comment: @homogenity : what do you mean "see above...." you have not said anything... you said $g(x)\geq 0$ but not why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$g(0)=f(0)-0\geq 0$$
$$g\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=f\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right )=f\left( \frac{\pi}{4}\right)-1\leq 0$$
therefore, $\exists x\in [0,\frac{\pi}{4}]$ such that
$$g(x)=f(x)-\sin(2x)=0$$
And of course $\frac{\pi}{4}\leq 1$